# if two arduinos are connected by I2C and one of them is using an ethernet shield, does that grant both of them access to the internet?

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet, web-server, ethernet-shield

i have two arduino mega and they send data to each other by an I2C connection. But one of those arduinos is connected to an ethernet shield which allows it to send data to a web server. Being both connected does that mean that they both can send or access the web server. Sorry if any ambiguity was found but I didnt find a better way to ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I2C does not automatically share resources between two connected devices. You would not be able to share an Internet connection from a Mega connected via I2C to another Mega which has an Ethernet shield.

However, you **could** write code for both Megas that implements a two-way communication in which the non-shield Mega sends requests or commands to the one with the Shield, and then passes that data back to the non-shield Mega.

However, you, as the coder, would be responsible for designing such a protocol and implementing it. It would be quite a task probably.

Comment: Thank you my friend, this couldn't be answered better.

Answer (score 2):

It can but only if the one with the shield allows it (it acts like a router).

The only way for the arduino without the shield can communicate with the internet if it can send a message to the one with the shield and it will forward that message and return the replies back.